# A subset of a finite dimensional normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

This was left as an unproved theorem in our class:

Theroem:  If $X$ is a  finite dimensional normed vector space then each subset $M$ of $X$ is compact if and only if $M$ is closed and bounded.

How do I prove it? I know that $M$ is also finte dimensional and hence complete. So it is bounded.

Comment: If $X$ has dimension $n$, then $X$ is isomorphic to Euclidean $n$-space. Use the Heine-Borel Theorem.

Comment: In your theorem, did you want to say: "If X is a finite dimensional normed vector space then *a* subset $M$ of $X$ is compact if and only if $M$ is closed and bounded."?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Would the proof then be a one line proof?

Comment: Yes, more or less, as long as you've already proven the two ingredients (Heine-Borel for $\Bbb R^n$ and the fact that two finite dimensional normed spaces of the same dimension are  isomorphic).

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok. I've only seen Heine Borel for $\mathbb{R}$. The other fact has already been proven in class.

Answer (score 4):

$Hint$ If $X$ has dimension $n$ then $X$ is  linearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.